# IntelliJ PHP Interpreter not finding homebrew installed PHP in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, homebrew

IntelliJ will not detect installed PHP even though it does exist and can be used from the command line.  I have installed php via `brew install php54`.  Below is a screenshot of my issue along with evidence that it does exist.  I've tried clicking the refresh button many times, but it will not pick up the binary.

[image: picture of issue]

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No, not completely yet.  There is one possible solution below, but I need more instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just now come back to this after some time and it looks like the latest version IntelliJ works with PHP installed via Homebrew.  So I'm going to mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem.  Through some hackery, I discovered it was due to some ansi escape sequences in my prompt.  From your screenshot it looks like you might have the same or a similar issue.

Essentially, IntelliJ uses a php script to create an XML string out of some PHP configuration items, including $_SERVER.  The $_SERVER superglobal contains environment variables and therefore picked up the escape character (0x1b) in the sequence.  Since the escape character is invalid in XML, IntelliJ rejected the output and concluded the PHP interpreter was bad.

Once I removed the ansi sequences from my prompt, IntelliJ recognized the PHP interpreter right away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question!  I'm not quite sure what I can do to make sure I don't have escaped characters in my path.  Can you describe a bit better how I can fix this? Thanks again :).

Comment: They wouldn't be in your path, but in your prompt.  Go through your .bashrc or .bash_profile and look for a line that starts with "PS1=" or "export PS1=".  A Google search might help here too.

Comment: This works for me, thanks. After you've "fixed" your prompt, do not forget to restart IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: You may also try to turn off color support in your term on period of php detecting

Comment: This was exactly the issue for me, though removing the escapes from PS1 alone was not enough. Using the PHP cli, I vardumped the $_SERVER superglobal and grep'd the escape character, found that I had also modified PS2.

`php -r 'var_dump($_SERVER);' | grep -nB1 --color=none $'\x1b'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it turned out my Homebrew install was severely out of date when I installed PHP. To fix it, I ran:

`brew update && brew upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

With some quick help from jetbrains support, the latest EAP version fixed it for me: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23045

If you prefer to keep investigating the issue, see Chris' answer and search the idea.log for something like:

```
INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/php.xml file is null
```

[idea.log locations](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108)